# Ошибка при выводе title в теле страницы

Tags: битрикс

Создал страницу хочу вывести TIRLE но вместо этого выводит ошибку.
подскажите как пофиксить баг и вывести title

код

```
    <?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Тестовая с левым меню");

$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("tags", "5");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("ROBOTS", "index, follow5");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("TITLE", "о нас | Вот так");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("keywords", "Keywords5");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", "Description5");

?>


<?= 'description =' . $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description"); ?>
<br>

Text here....

О нас <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

ошибка которая выходит на странице

### [ArgumentCountError]
Too few arguments to function CAllMain::SetPageProperty(), 1 passed in /Users/arthorias/Desktop/sites/RelexSite/about/index.php on line 14 and at least 2 expected (0)
/Users/arthorias/Desktop/sites/RelexSite/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/main.php:500
#0: CAllMain->SetPageProperty(string)
/Users/arthorias/Desktop/sites/RelexSite/about/index.php:14

Comment: Здесь вывожу description Но его можно поменять на TITLE и выйдет иа же ошибка Вывод делаю в  <?= 'description =' . $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description"); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете функцию SetPageProperty, она используется для установки свойства страницы и принимает 2 параметра, на что и указывает ошибка, а для вывода используются функции [ShowProperty](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/showproperty.php), [GetPageProperty](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/getpageproperty.php), [GetProperty](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/getproperty.php)